# What is the generalization of monotone increase from functions to correspondence?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I just learned the generalization of continuity. What about monotonicity for a correspondence $F:\mathbb R\to2^\mathbb R$?

For example, intuitively, imagine that a monotone increase function is translating and deforming on the $\mathbb R^2$ plane, then we could define that all the covered path of such translation is the graph of a monotonically increasing correspondence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are so-called **monotone operators**.  A multivalued map $A$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is called *monotone* if for any $x,y\in H$ and $ u \in Ax, v\in Ay$ it holds that
$$
\langle u-v,x-y\rangle \geq 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you! However, when $u$ and $v$ are sets: $u,y\subset\mathbb R$, how do we define $(u-v)$ and the dot product between a set and a number?

Comment: No, $Ax$ and$Ay$ are sets ($F(x)$ and $F(y)$ in your notation). The inequality has to hold for all elements $u,v$ of these sets, respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand it now

Comment: Is it possible to have a weaker version of definition like $\forall x,y\in H\forall v\in Ay\exists u\in Ax$ such that $\langle u-v,x-y \rangle\geq 0$?

Comment: Sure, why not? I have not seen this notion before, though.